# Click the last but one checkbox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

In a page there are *n* number of checkboxes. Each time the page refreshes the list of checkboxes will also be refreshed and can be a different size. How do I click the second last (last but one) checkbox every time?

Answer (score 3):

Locate all checkboxes i.e.:

```
List<WebElements> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By...)
```

Now, for a 0-based list, the last element will be `checkboxes.size()-1`, so what we want to do is:

```
if (checkboxes.size() > 0) {
        if (checkboxes.size() > 1) {
            checkboxes.get(checkboxes.size() - 2).click();
        } else {
            //either select the last and only checkbox or throw an error
        }
    } else {
        //handle the error as list was empty
    }
```

As this will select the **second last** element.

Comment: I would suggest checkboxes.size() == 0 || checkboxes.size() == 1, so you don't have to have nested conditions.

Comment: It would even br enough to check if the list is bigger then 1, but we do not know if a single checkbox scenario is a valid case, hence the nested if.